# Inconsistent specialization of tuple_size

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

When explicitly specializing both `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` for some template, I realized that §14.5.1/4, which reads

> In a redeclaration, partial specialization, explicit specialization or
>   explicit instantiation of a class template, **the *class-key* shall agree
>   in kind with the original class template declaration** (7.1.6.3).

is seemingly violated by the standard itself:

[image]

Am I missing something here (e.g. the standard specifies that *class-key*s are "exposition only" and shall agree within the actual implementation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bo Persson's now-deleted answer got it right. The paragraph ([temp.class]/p4) you cite refers to §7.1.6.3 [dcl.type.elab] for the definition of "agree in kind", which in turn says (p3, emphasis mine)

> The *class-key* or `enum` keyword present in the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the *elaborated-type-specifier* refers. This rule
>   also applies to the form of
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* that declares a *class-name* or friend class since it can be construed as referring to the definition of the
>   class. Thus, in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword
>   shall be used to refer to an enumeration (7.2), the `union`
>   *class-key* shall be used to refer to a union (Clause 9), and **either the `class` or `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a class
>   (Clause 9) declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key***.

The code is valid, if inconsistent.

Comment: Oh. I didn't fully realize that it said 'in kind'.

Comment: One OT-question: What is your preferred way of referring to the specific spot of the standard that a quote resides in? I.e., §i.j.k/m or [Abc.def]/m, or both?

Comment: @Columbo Too bad SO doesn't let you do polls.

Comment: @Columbo I try to always have [abc.def] because that's least likely to change between drafts/revisions and is also somewhat descriptive. I'm too lazy to also add the section number most of the time :), unless the number is being referenced (e.g., 7.1.6.3 in your quote)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an editorial defect to me.  Try opening an issue here:

https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues

If you're adventurous, try resolving it with a pull request. :-)

Comment: Do you think that, although the relevant paragraph is not defective, an adjustment would be appropriate?

Comment: @Columbo:  Yes.  Additionally I think such an adjustment could be made editorially.  That means that the committee does not have to vote on it.  It is done at the editor's discretion.  This answer gives instructions for communicating with the editor.

Comment: Well, I don't feel adventurous today. ;-) https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/534